# bootstrap mail form $from<$email>

Tags: php, email, html-email, mail-form, formmail

I refer to this page. 
https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

i want mailheader "name"

but this php code is

```js
<?php

// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

so i tried

$sendTo = 'Demo contact form ';  => my mail.

$from = 'Demo contact form '; => $name <'$email'>
 but the result is "nobody"

So i tried again.

```js
 $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
```

=>

```js
 $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from<$email>,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
```

But it failed...

what should i do?

i tried

From: $FromName  and

$headers = "From: $from_user \r\n". and

$headers .= 'From: "'. $from . '" <' . $Email . '>' . "\r\n";  etc...

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));

$from = "$name<$email_address>";
```